# How to access PermisionNames in sitemap?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am working on nopcommerce and i have created one store. In that store i want to add one page in Promotions in Admin Section. For that i have created **My View, Model & Controller** in Nop.Admin Project.

Following is the code I have in sitemap.config file

```
<siteMapNode title="Promotions" nopResource="Admin.Promotions" PermissionNames="ManageAffiliates, ManageNewsletterSubscribers, ManageCampaigns, ManageDiscounts" ImageUrl="~/Administration/Content/images/ico-promotions.png">
          <siteMapNode title="Affiliates" nopResource="Admin.Affiliates" PermissionNames="ManageAffiliates" controller="Affiliate" action="List" />
          <siteMapNode title="Newsletter subscriptions" nopResource="Admin.Promotions.NewsletterSubscriptions" PermissionNames="ManageNewsletterSubscribers" controller="NewsLetterSubscription" action="List" />
          <siteMapNode title="Campaigns" nopResource="Admin.Promotions.Campaigns" PermissionNames="ManageCampaigns" controller="Campaign" action="List" />
          <siteMapNode title="Discounts" nopResource="Admin.Promotions.Discounts" PermissionNames="ManageDiscounts" controller="Discount" action="List" />
          <siteMapNode title="Get Quote" nopResource="Admin.Promotions.GetQuotesubscriptions" PermissionNames="Manage" controller="GetQuote" action="GetQuoteList" />
        </siteMapNode>
```

In above code, i have added my fifth node as GetquoteList and have the following code in StandardPermissionProvider.cs file

```
public static readonly PermissionRecord ManageGetQuotesubscribers = new PermissionRecord { Name = "Admin area. Manage GetQuote Subscibers", SystemName = "ManageGetQuoteSubscribers", Category = "Promo" };
```

But it doesn't display menu item in admin side.

If i replace `PermissionName="ManageGetQuoteSubscribers"` with `"ManageDiscount"`, then it display's it. I am unable to understand the problem.

Can anyone help me ?

All answers are accepted.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Is ManageGetQuotesubscribers also in the PermissionRecord table in the DB?